# Make the present count meaning

Tags: meaning

Kindly tell me what is the meaning of *make the present count* in this sentence from  the last sentence of [an article run by the Dawn.COM electronic newspaper](http://www.dawn.com/news/1149237/pak-afghan-ties-a-fresh-start):

> The leaderships on both sides need to make the present count.

Comment: make the present, useful, helpful , positive. To count: to have a specified importance or value:

Comment: Never cite something without giving a proper reference to where you took your citation from. Otherwise people cannot tell the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> count (intransitive verb) - to have value or significance [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/count)

If context is about "peace talks", I would say it means...

> "The leadership on both sides should not miss the chances they have at present" or "..."should make the best of the present moment."